# double x labels do not match (set_xlim)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I would like to plot two twiny x axis, according to https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2018/01/add-second-x-axis-below-first-x-axis-python-matplotlib-pyplot.html

My original data is 
[image]

My code :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
index = data.coin
rects1 = ax.bar(index, data['message_count'])
ax.set_xlabel('Group')
ax.set_ylabel('message count')
ax.set_title('')
ax.legend()

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xticklabels(data.create_date)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom') # set the position of the second x-axis to bottom
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom') # set the position of the second x-axis to bottom
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 38))
ax2.set_xlabel('Create Date')
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
```

The plot I have:
[image]

I dont know why the second axis does not match with the first one. I have tried adjusting the `ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())` but in vain.

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont know why the second axis does not match with the first one."? They are matching perfectly and the ticks are aligned on top of each other. What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Bazingaa The bottom labels are all shifted one position to the left. Compare the input table with the two sets of plot labels. That is also why the last item doesn't have a date label.

Comment: @9769953 Exactly!

Comment: Please make sure you create a *full* working example, including imports *and data*. The picture of your table 1/ is hard to read, 2/ is not copy-pasteable, 3/ is not copy-pasteable into a DataFrame, 4/ contains extra, unnecessary and distracting columns (such as two index columns, while in the code the "coin" column is used as index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the x limit on the second axes objecct also changes the default x-tick positions for that axes. You can find how by printing `ax2.get_xticks()` before and after the `ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())` call.

You need to explicitly (re)set the x-tick positions once you change the x-limit, with `ax2.set_xticks()`, and set them to those for `ax`.

Below is a full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'message_count': [557, 119, 108, 14, 9],
                   'coin': ['MEDX', 'CNX', 'IOST', 'AUTO', 'PPT'],
                   'create_date': ['2018-08-03 03:05:00',
                                   '2017-08-10 14:33:45',
                                   '2018-07-20 18:32:45',
                                   '2017-12-08 15:09:42',
                                   '2017-07-24 14:11:22']})
df['create_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'])
print(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
index = df.coin
rects1 = ax.bar(index, df['message_count'])
ax.set_xlabel('Group')
ax.set_ylabel('message count')
ax.set_title('')
ax.legend()

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xticklabels(df.create_date)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom') # set the position of the second x-axis to bottom
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom') # set the position of the second x-axis to bottom
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 38))
ax2.set_xlabel('Create Date')
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('twinplot.png')
```

which yields

[image]